# Issue in Angular Universal Deployment

Tags: angular, angular-universal

How do i deploy my universal app in servers like tomcat as I deploy my other angular apps in tomcat only.

Also whats the best way/server to deploy angular universal app

Comment: Can you install nodejs just for anguar universal? It does not have to be exposed publicly, your tomcat can proxy the request to that server internally. Angular universal is only officiallysupported for nodejs and asp.net core servers at the moment.

Comment: So i have to run it on a node server?

Comment: Yes, for now that is the only supported way, with asp.net core. Otherwise, did you check the link provided by @whto? There were some attemps at using java and angular, such as https://github.com/swaechter/angularj-universal

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Answer (score 1):

You can't deploy universal apps just like any other SPA or Non-SPA, you will need a real server to run universal app.

You have to buy a server which runs applications on node, Here is a link to buy node server, few of them are free for limited users

http://www.hostingadvice.com/blog/where-to-find-free-node-js-hosting/

You can pm2 as a service for node, here's link to [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/)

Comment: TomCat is not a Webserver that can only serve static files (like e. g. Apache), it should be possible and there are discussions about it going on here: https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/280

Comment: True. But the questioner did, so it seemed to me your answer was opposing the use of TomCat.

Comment: I dont want to buy hosting I have to do it on my own.
Can tomcat jboss do it?

Comment: that link have list of free hostings, whatever hosting you see, search if is it possible to use a webserver or can run through node